# Do cauldrons catch rainwater?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I can't remember when or where I saw it, but at one point I remember being able to fill a cauldron with rainwater.

Is this possible in Vanilla Minecraft?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To quote the [Minecraft wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Cauldron#Usage):

> A cauldron slowly fills with water when rained upon, if starting empty or with some water. This happens randomly, at 5% of the rate in which snow accumulates on the ground during snowfall.

Yes, it has a chance to fill it. In fact someone even built a machine that fills them when it rains and I suspect you could use them as a type of rain detector with a comparator.

Comment: does someone knows what is the chance (%)?

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/JwZK1qd.png (from MCP) which basically means a 1 in 20 chance roughly, which is ran about 1:16 chance when it rains/snows  each tick.. so not very often.

Answer (score 2):

**Cauldrons do collect rainwater, however, it is only by chance.**

> A cauldron also has a chance to fill up with water when rained upon.

According to the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Cauldron#Usage).